# Category id in category permalink, woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add category id in the category permalink setings of woocommerce? I know this displays the category slug ( /%product_cat%/ ). What I need is something like this: /%product_cat_id%/

Comment: weird way to ruin your SEO score.. but I don't see any options for it either in the docs. - Guessing you will have to write some custom rewrite rules in your functions.php

Comment: Or is it possible to get the id knowing just the category url. So I have multiple tags <a href="cat_url"><span>cat_id</span></a>. This list of tags is displayed in the main menu

Comment: that could be `$theTerm = get_term_by('slug','YourCatSlugHere', 'product_cat', 'object');` and then use it like `$theTerm->term_id;` i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution if anyone else needs it:

```
function category_id_in_menu( $classes, $item ){
    if( 'product_cat' == $item->object ){
        $classes[] = 'category-id-' . $item->object_id;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'category_id_in_menu', 10, 2 );
```